# Memory Leak with Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.0 Beta 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-leaks

I have tried various combinations and find that by simply generating a skeleton Rails 3.0 application, and then running

siege http://localhost:3000

My ruby process would then leak a few MB every 5 minutes.

The reason I tried this is because I just converted a full blown Rails 2.3 and Ruby Enterprise 1.8.6 application over to Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.0 Beta 4 and find that my app is leaking memory.

This happens for both development and production environment, however happens a lot faster in development.

I do not think this is a specific Rails 3.0 problem because I am also experiencing the same with Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.9.2

So it is probably how Ruby 1.9.2 is interacting with Rails.

I never had such problem with Ruby Enterprise 1.8.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an excellent presentation on how to tackle Ruby memory leak problems [here](http://blog.envylabs.com/2010/07/garbage-collection-the-ruby-heap/)

Answer (score 0):

As I've written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582338/rails-3-1-memory-leak-for-missing-local-partial-variables-ruby-1-9-2-p290/7706383#7706383), one (or even several) blatant memory leaks were fixed in 1.9.3-rc1.