# Rails 3.1, memory leak for missing local partial variables (Ruby 1.9.2-p290)

Tags: memory-leaks, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.2

If I render a partial like so:

= render :partial => "event_news_item", :object => event,  :variable => true

And then reference *variable* in the partial a memory leak is triggered. It seems rails goes into a recursion. I have to then quickly restart my server before memory usage spirals out of control.

**Anyone knows why the memory leak is triggered here? Can anyone confirm this on their machine?**

If I do

= render :partial => "event_news_item", :object => event

An error is raised correctly when trying to reference *variable* in the partial.

(The correct way of doing this by the way is

= render :partial => "event_news_item", :object => event,  :locals => { :variable => true })

Comment: I can confirm that same behavior occurs randomly in dev mode when I have missing local var/method in helper(s). I think this is because Rails is crap and more specifically because view helpers are entangled method_missing-empowered spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a really bad memory leak in similar environment. I've tracked it to the innocently looking association fetch (`comment.author`, to be precise), then tried to debug it for some time, and finally gave up and ran on 1.9.3-rc1.

Surprisingly, that fixed this particular memory leak, and, moreover, reduced the unicorns' startup size by 15M (from 85M to 70M; i386).

Comment: The memory savings sound amazing, I might give 1.9.3 a try. However, I'm on Heroku and they use 1.9.2. So it is not really an option for me currently.

Comment: If any C-level leak (i.e. not your fault) manifests itself on your Heroku host, that's not your headache. Matz [himself](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/7/12/matz_joins_heroku/) works with them ;) and a bunch of other great programmers too. If you're talking about compatibility, you can just refrain from using [the new APIs](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_3_preview1/NEWS), which is not very difficult.

Comment: I have the same problem -- upgrading to 1.9.3 didn't seem to fix it though.