# Will this type of render create memory bloats in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memory

I have four different Rails-apps (ruby 2.3.3/rails 4.1.13) on Heroku running on Unicorn (1 worker per app).

Two of them have a few thousand visitors per day, the other two around hundred a day. They all have a major issue in common: They are always running out on memory on Heroku! They are almost always above 100% of the 500 Mb limit on Heroku, thus using the slow Swap-memory. As all 4 share the same issue, I believe there is something in my programming habits that cause this - and possibly the way I render sub-items in partial lists (specifically after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582338/rails-3-1-memory-leak-for-missing-local-partial-variables-ruby-1-9-2-p290)). I would like to hear whether this code is likely to bloat memory in my apps:

I have three files (the code obviously is quite simplified):

```
#show
render 'partials/product_list', :vars => { :products => Product.where(:foo => "bar"), :display_format => :grid }

#partials/product_list
<% if vars[:products].empty? %>
No products exist
<% else %>
  <% if vars[:display_format].eql?(:grid) %>
    <div class="abc">
      <% vars[:products].each do |product|
        <%= render 'partials/product_item', :product => product %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% elsif vars[:display_format].eql?(:wide) %>
  <ul>
      <% vars[:products].each do |product|
        <li><%= render 'partials/product_item', :product => product %></li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
  <% elsif vars[:display_format].eql?(:rectangular) %>
  <div class="ghi">
<ul class="rectangular_container">
      <% vars[:products].each do |product|
        <li class="rectangle"><%= render 'partials/product_item', :product => product %></li>
      <% end %>
</ul>
  </div>
<% else %>
<div class="jkl">
      <% vars[:products].each do |product|
        <%= render 'partials/product_item', :product => product %>
      <% end %>
</div>
<% end >

#partials/product_item
<% if vars[:display_format].eql?(:wide) %>
  <h1><%= product.name %></h1>
  <p><%= product.description %></p>
<% elsif vars[:display_format].eql?(:rectangular)%>
  // Similar but with lots of divs and other html
<% end %>
```

This may seem very weird but I reference partials/product_list from here and there all over the website (with different layouts and different product sets) and if I want to change the setup of e.g. grid-layout, I want to do it in one place only.

I have started using references in #show with `Product.all.pluck(:id)` and in partials/product_item start with `product = Product.find(vars[:product])` but I can't really tell if this is making any difference. Edit: As max says in the comments, this is probably less efficient due to the amount of .find-calls I need to do.

Before I dig really deep into this, I have a few questions:

1. Is this something that strikes you as: "YES, this type of rendering will bloat your memory!"
2. If yes: How should I solve this type of rendering without memory problems?
3. Would there be a difference if I would use :collection, :layout etc instead of my own variables?

Any light on this issue would be highly appreciated!

Comment: So to summarise your question: "Does loading lots of partials cause big memory bloat?" No, not necessarily. That *could* be the issue, but it's pure speculation. Why don't you experiment with some [profiling tools](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/03/01/which-rails-profiler-is-right-for-you), and investigate the true bottlenecks? This will also help you to see whether your changes are helping.

Comment: There are lots of *other* things you could be doing to improve performance - look through the [many different types of caching in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html), for instance. Or maybe you could add (or remove?!) some database indexes? Or maybe you need to tweak the unicorn config so that resources are shared between the applications more appropriately?

Comment: This is a very broad question; I can't really diagnose and solve your problem in a single StackOverflow answer. But hopefully this points you in some good directions.

Comment: Side note: With all that complex view logic, you may benefit from doing some refactoring. One interesting library you could consider using is [`cells`](https://github.com/trailblazer/cells).

Comment: Calling `Product.all` and iterating is more effiecient than doing `Product.all.pluck(:id)` than re-looking up each of the records using `find`. This is because the repeated SQL reads will be a bottleneck. Not sure if this causes the performance error, though.

Comment: Tom: Thanks for your comments! I should specify the question to if THIS particular way of rendering partials is bad coding in terms of memory. The question seems broader than it actually is as I want to give as much side information as possible. I have tried a LOT of memory profiling tools but I find it hard to use them in a way that would pinpoint my (possible) problem.

Comment: Tom: I am using caching quite a bit, perhaps not 100% effectively but as much as I can. I am also using database indexes. But please note that this is not a question about general memory performance but whether this type of rendering is bad.

Comment: max: I thought about that some time after I wrote the question. You are probably right! Good thing you said so before I tried this in every section of the app.

Comment: I would render the collection type of variables via the render collection method which will clean up a lot of the each blocks in the view code http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections

Comment: I wonder how many products does this `Product.where(:foo => "bar")` query usually return?

Answer (score 1):

One issue that stands out to me is it looks like you're doing some lookups in your views and breaking the MVC pattern. In my opinion, you should put that code into the controller for that action

so rewrite this line:

```
render 'partials/product_list', :vars => { :products => Product.where(:foo => "bar"), :display_format => :grid }
```

to this:

```
# in show controller action 
@products = Product.all # <- This will get cached by rails

# in view 
render 'partials/product_list', :vars => { :products => @products, :display_format => :grid }
```

Removing the Product call in the view and replacing it an instance variable that [rails will cache](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching). Keep in mind default rails cache is memory based. Which may be causing some of the bloat as your data grows. If you have memcache available perhaps changing your cache store to memcache would help too.

You can just chain a where clauses to your instance variable like you do now and the AREL will handle it.

```
# partial rendering with chained scope
render 'partials/product_list', :vars => { :products => @products.where(foo: "bar"), :display_format => :grid }
```

If you are finding that further filtering of items is becoming a common pattern, then you can use a scope in your Products model that will be chainable on the @products instance variable. This will keep it in AREL (SQL) and maintain the lazy loading/query caching while simplifying your code a bit.

```
# in Products model
scope :filter_to_bar, -> (term) {where(foo: term)}

# partial rendering with chained scope
render 'partials/product_list', :vars => { :products => @products.filter_to_bar("bar"), :display_format => :grid }
```

Personally I say keep your data fetches in SQL when you can, as this puts the strain on SQL and is lazy loaded, i.e. doesn't affect ruby memory. SQL done properly is fast, ruby is much slower and more memory intensive. SQL is only slow when your queries are O^n or you're making repeated small queries and putting unneccessary hits on the database. In that case, fetch the data and work with it on the rails application as suggested. While this will add to the memory consumption of your application is consuming, it will be more performant.

One thing you can do to speed up SQL fetches is to implement pagination tables or some sort of infinite scroll mechanism. This way you only load the data you need when you need it.

Also if you want a faster version of rails' partial pattern, check out the cells gem as suggested. It will require some refactoring but should be faster than rails' pure partials. However, caching will probably take you much further with less refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. Unfortunately, I tried to keep things as simple as possible in my question and I do not actually have the lookup in the view. I do use cache, pagination etc as well. I will definetely lookup cell once again, as well as collections. I think for this particular memory bloat-question I have to subdivide it into more specific questions. Thanks for your effort, although it didn't quite solve my problem.